# SQL Server Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, case-statement

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
AgentID varchar(5),
AgentName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES ('A111A', 'Yes'), ('A111G', 'Yes'), ('A111M', 'Yes')

SELECT AgentID,
       CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%A' THEN AgentName END AS [A Agent],
       CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%G' THEN AgentName END AS [G Agent],
       CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%M' THEN AgentName END AS [M Agent]
 FROM #table1
DROP TABLE #table1
```

When I run the above code I get the following:

```
AgentID A Agent G Agent M Agent
A111A   Yes     NULL    NULL
A111G   NULL    Yes     NULL
A111M   NULL    NULL    Yes
```

I want to find a way to get the following result (Since the agent 111 has all Agent types):

```
 Agent   AAgent GAgent MAgent
 111     Yes    Yes    Yes
```

Comment: Is `AgentID` always going to be in the format shown in the sample? And always 3 rows for each numeric value?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Yes, it will be always the same format, I know how to do this part, it is fairly easy but the part where I eliminate the NULLS is the one I am not getting.

Comment: One more check - is 'A112A' a likely value or 'B111A' or both?

Comment: No, B111A is not likely a value, all Agents start with A then the 3 digit numbers then ends with A, or G, or M.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I have added my answer based on them.

Comment: The value A111G must be mixing 2 items if the 111 is really an AgentID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(AgentId,2,3) AS AgentID,
      MAX(CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%A' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [A Agent],
      MAX(CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%G' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [G Agent],
      MAX(CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%M' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [M Agent]
    FROM #table1
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(AgentId,2,3)
    ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(AgentId,2,3),
        (SELECT CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%A' THEN AgentName END FROM #table1 WHERE AgentID = t1.AgentID) AS [A Agent],
        (SELECT CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%G' THEN AgentName END FROM #table1 WHERE AgentID = t1.AgentID)  AS [G Agent],
        (SELECT CASE WHEN AgentID LIKE 'A%M' THEN AgentName END FROM #table1 WHERE AgentID = t1.AgentID) AS [M Agent]
FROM #table1 t1
DROP TABLE #table1
```

You are better off using a table variable however, as those are only in memory and don't hit tempdb

```
DECLARE @my_temp_table TABLE
(
   myintcol int,
   myvarcharcol varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @my_temp_table (myintcol, myvarcharcol) VALUES(1,'some-text')
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I already have a table, I just created a temp table for testing purposes, the code you wrote still does not help! I am not getting a 1 row of result with 3 yes in each column.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: Format of `AgentID` is always of the form `A[0-9][0-9][0-9](A|G|M)`

```
;with cte as
(select substring(agentid,2,3) id, count(agentname) count
 from #table1
 where agentname IS NOT NULL --Simply check that it is not null; values may not be identical
 group by substring(agentid,2,3)
 having count(*) = 3)

 select id as Agent, 'Yes' as AAgent, 'Yes' as GAgent, 'Yes' as MAgent from cte
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/YFNVC98330).

To get actual agent names, use this query:

```
select distinct id as Agent
,(select agentname from #table1 t1 where substring(t1.agentid,2,3) = c.id and right(t1.agentid,1) = 'A') as AAgent
,(select agentname from #table1 t2 where substring(t2.agentid,2,3) = c.id and right(t2.agentid,1) = 'G') as GAgent
,(select agentname from #table1 t3 where substring(t3.agentid,2,3) = c.id and right(t3.agentid,1) = 'M') as MAgent
from cte c
inner join #table1 t on c.id = substring(t.agentid,2,3)
```

Comment: Please do not worry about the AgentID, I already figured that out. The only problem I see in the above solution is the following, it will not always be as 'Yes' That actualy is the A agent name and the G agent name and the M agent name. Since I really do not know what are the agent names (In the example I have as 'yes') the solution above will not work.

Comment: So it can be any non-null value, but not necessarily the same for all 3?

Comment: @user3345212 Updated query.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question if that is OK, how can I display the actual AgentName instead of yes? For example if in my table I have the following:

Comment: INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES ('A111A', 'AAA'), ('A111G', 'BBB'), ('A111M', 'CCC')

Comment: If two are true (A Agent, G Agent) and 1 is false (M Agent), then this will return no rows?

Comment: @JBrooks This only checks for non-null values, not the actual value. As OP clarified, the non-null values may be different for each row.

Comment: @user3345212 Why the unaccept? I know it's your choice, but I'd like to understand how my query can be improved.